# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString does not work

Tags: javascript, iphone, xcode

I am trying to call a javascript function from loaded local html file in `UIWebView`
but it deosn't respond

it look like this

```
NSString *script=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sample()"];

if (tekst.loading) {
    NSLog(@"Loading");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Fully loaded");
    [tekst stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
}
```

and in html

```
<head>
....
<script type='text/javascript'>
function sample() {
alert('Paznja');
}
</script>
...
</head>
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but no need to call `stringWithFormat:` here.  Just assign the string literal directly:  
    NSString *script = @"sample()";

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks to me as if you are not using a delegate on your UIWebView. If you set a delegate and put the call to the Javascript into the "- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView " method, it works fine:

```
UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 700.0, 700.0)];
[self.view addSubview:wv];
wv.delegate = self;
[wv loadHTMLString:@"<html><head><script type='text/javascript'>function sample() {alert('Paznja');}</script></head><body><h1>TEST</h1></body></html>" baseURL:nil];
[wv release];
```

and in the same class:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
   [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"sample()"];
}
```

When I run this code, the alert message works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Additional note, if you are expecting an object back from the javascript function rather than a string then do the following:

```
NSString *json = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"JSON.stringify(TestMethod())"];
```