# How can I pass an NSArray to JavaScript file and print that array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova, nsarray

I am looking for send one NSArray from viewcontroller.m file to data.js file
but its not printing anything in JavaScript. Following is my code.

In my viewdidload method

```
   - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    // Black base color for background matches the native apps
    CDV=[[CDVViewController alloc]init];
    news=[[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"latest news" ofType:@"plist"]];
    NSArray *newsItems=[[NSArray alloc]init];
    newsItems=[news valueForKey:@"News"];
    NSData *jsonArray = [self arrayToJSON:newsItems];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonArray
                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *jsCall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"yourJsFunction([%@])", jsonString];
    [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCall];
   NSLog(@"%@",jsonString);
   // theWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    return [super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView];
}


   - (NSData *) arrayToJSON:(NSArray *) inputArray
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    id result = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:inputArray
                                                options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if (error != nil) return nil;
    return result;
}
```

And in my one.js file I have this code:

```
function yourJsFunction(arr){
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        document.write(arr[i]);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Output is:

ഡാറ്റാ സെന്റര്‍ കേസ്: സത്യവാങ്മൂലം സമര്‍പ്പിക്കാന്‍ അനുമതി‌,കാശ്മീര്‍ നയത്തില്‍ മാറ്റമില്ലെന്ന് യു.എസ്‌",നിതാഖാത്‌ സമയപരിധി തീരാന്‍ 14 ദിവസം മാത്രം; ഇനി പിടിക്കപ്പെട്ടാല്‍ ജയില്‍ശിക്ഷയും പിഴയും‌,ഡീസല്‍ സബ്‌സിഡി: കെഎസ്ആര്‍ടിസി പുതിയ അപേക്ഷ സമര്‍പ്പിക്കണം‌

**But I want each of them separately instead of putting ","**

Current output:

[image]

New image
[image]

Comment: Try logging in console in yourJsFunction function, to be sure you're going there at first place.

Comment: Also it's possible your arr parameter to be an ivalid json

Comment: divaka:i didnt get you?

Comment: divaka:when i print json string value i got this  ["ഡാറ്റാ സെന്റര്‍ കേസ്: സത്യവാങ്മൂലം സമര്‍പ്പിക്കാന്‍ അനുമതി‌ ","കാശ്മീര്‍ നയത്തില്‍ മാറ്റമില്ലെന്ന് യു.എസ്‌","നിതാഖാത്‌ സമയപരിധി തീരാന്‍ 14 ദിവസം മാത്രം; ഇനി പിടിക്കപ്പെട്ടാല്‍ ജയില്‍ശിക്ഷയും പിഴയും‌ ","ഡീസല്‍ സബ്‌സിഡി: കെഎസ്ആര്‍ടിസി പുതിയ അപേക്ഷ സമര്‍പ്പിക്കണം‌ "]

Comment: It seems valid. What about encoding? Is it UTF-8? You could also try printing arrayFromiOS.

Comment: no am not encoding it

Comment: You are not encoding it, but when you create the .plist file it has some encoding. Try printing arrayFromiOS after you parsing the arr parameter.

Comment: ok let me try and i will let u knwpo

Comment: Divaka:this line is not printing anything for(var i=0;i<arrayFromiOS.length;i++){
                            document.write(arrayFromiOS[i]);
                        }

Comment: In `yourJsFuncion` print `arr` parameter before `var arrayFromiOS = JSON.parse(arr);` line and after this line print `arrayFromiOS`

Comment: its not printing anything...how do i know whether its executing or not???

Comment: Check your javascript console on your browser?

Comment: but am running all these from xcode ryt

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656544/stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring-does-not-work

Comment: You need `(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` method, and there you should put `[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCall];`

Comment: have added that one still not working

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042480/uiwebview-stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring-isnt-calling-javascript-functi

Comment: i think my problem is index.html not linking that js file

Comment: How are you loading it?

Comment: Take a look at this. It could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733883/loading-javascript-into-a-uiwebview-from-resources/13473498

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="main1.js"></script>

Comment: Why main1.js? The function is in data.js? Check the links I gave you!

Comment: i just rename that data.js to main1.js

Comment: Check the links I gave you. How did you add data.js to your resources?

Comment: now the html links with js file ,but its still not printing anything

Comment: Maybe it's not properly linked. did you check the links I gave you?

Comment: If you want them separate use js `split` method.

Comment: divaka:yes ..i hav checked those links..now am able to get data .

Comment: So now what is the problem? You want to separate a string by ','?

Comment: Please check the image in my question.. it showing all four elements with ","  but i want to display only one of them

Comment: i have tried split  in js but its not working

Comment: One on each row? Where did you apply .split method? I'm pretty sure your `arr` in `yourJsFunction` consists of 1 element

Comment: i have tried some thing like    var value=arr;
    var i=value.split(",");
    document.write(i);   but its printing anything

Comment: Could you print `arr.length` in `yourJsMethod`

Comment: yup i print that one  document.write(arr.length);   result is  1

Comment: Try changing option here `NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:` from `kNilOptions` to `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted`

Comment: If this does not work in `yourJsFunction` at the top add `arr = arr[0].split(',');`

Comment: the split option is not even showing ,please check the new image in my question.and  i have made change in NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted but it still showing length =1

Comment: Add `arr = arr[0].split(',');` at the beginning of `yourJsfunction`;

Comment: u mean arr = arr.split(',')????

Comment: it's obvious that you arr contains 1 element, which is "aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd". So you get the first element with `arr[0]`, make array out of it by splitting on ',' and the rest code stays the same

Comment: its not showing "split" option it showing only "switch and "super"

Comment: `arr = arr[0].split` there is an index

Comment: i got the solution ,now its working ..first we have to convert that to a proper string using toString () then split that one.  var b=arr.toString().split(',');  now its working..thanks alot

Comment: divaka :wer r u from?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39649/discussion-between-divaka-and-navi)

Answer (score 1):

There are some changes in js file
1.Convert the arr to proper string using toString()
2.split that new string

var b=arr.toString().split(',');

now print   document.write(b[1]);  its working!!!!!

and in .m file   Like "@Divaka" 's option

Try changing option here NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: from kNilOptions to NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have passed a single string in `newsItems` variable. Then you call `yourJsFunction([%@])` - the argument is an array of your parameter (%@). Then you tried to print js object and got
`["ഡാറ്റാ സെന്റര്‍ കേസ്: സത്യവാങ്മൂലം സമര്‍പ്പിക്കാന്‍ അനുമതി‌ ","കാശ്മീര്‍ നയത്തില്‍ മാറ്റമില്ലെന്ന് യു.എസ്‌","നിതാഖാത്‌ സമയപരിധി തീരാന്‍ 14 ദിവസം മാത്രം; ഇനി പിടിക്കപ്പെട്ടാല്‍ ജയില്‍ശിക്ഷയും പിഴയും‌ ","ഡീസല്‍ സബ്‌സിഡി: കെഎസ്ആര്‍ടിസി പുതിയ അപേക്ഷ സമര്‍പ്പിക്കണം‌ "]` that is exactly array of one string object. Please check your file contents, i think it contain comma-separated values.
If it is then you have to break it into array of strings.

```
NSString *newsString = ...;// loading from plist
NSArray *newsItems = [newsString componentsSeparatedByString:","];
```

then serialize newsItems to json and call js function as

```
NSString *jsCall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"yourJsFunction(%@)", jsonString];
```

instead of

```
NSString *jsCall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"yourJsFunction([%@])", jsonString];
```